# Monotonic everywhere function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\forall x \in \mathbb R $ $\exists \delta \gt 0 : f$ is non-decreasing on $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$(I call that statement A). I need to prove that $f$ is non-decreasing on $\mathbb R$ (statement B).
I tried to go backwards: $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$. In words, that would be: if there is such $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R, x_1 \lt x_2, f(x_1)\gt f(x_2)$, then $\exists x\in \mathbb R, \forall \delta \gt 0 $ $\exists x_3,x_4 \in (x-\delta,x+\delta), x_3 \lt x_4, f(x_3) \gt f(x_4)$. I should find $x$ by using $x_1,x_2$. My problem is that I don't know how to do that. I know I supposed to use supremum of some set, but no more than that. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard argument based on compactness. Take $x<y$ and consider the compact interval $I=[x,y]$. Around each $x \in I$ you may find a small neighbourhood of the form $U_x=(x-\delta_x, x+\delta_x)$ on which your function is non-decreasing. Since $I \subset \bigcup \limits _{x \in I} U_x$ and I is compact, then there is a finite sub-covering of $I$ of the form $\bigcup \limits _{i=1} ^n U_{x_i}$ with $x_i \in I \space \forall i = 1 \dots n$ and $x_i < x_{i+1}$.

Now let $a \in U_{x_1} \setminus U_{x_2}$ and $b \in U_{x_2} \setminus U_{x_1}$, so $a \leq b$: choose some $c$ between $a$ and $b$, $c \in U_{x_1} \cap U_{x_2}$. Since $a,c \in U_{x_1}$, then $f(a) \leq f(c)$. Since $c,b \in U_{x_2}$, then $f(c) \leq f(b)$. Hence, $f(a) \leq f(b)$.

This is in fact a standard type of proof, and it took me more time to write it than it will take you to understand it.

Comment: "...then there is a finite subcovering of $I$ of the form ..."  The Heine-Borel theorem guarantees you a finite subcovering, it does not do any of the necessary bookkeeping  of organizing in this way for you.  So some comment seems needed.

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem provides a finite subcovering but, unless you are using a
 text that explicitly tells you how to arrange the sequence, you have to do it yourself.
 Fix   $x<y$.  Select $(x_1-\delta_1,x_1+\delta_1)$ from the subcover with maximal length
 and contains $x$.  Now select $(x_2-\delta_2,x_2+\delta_2)$
  with maximal length
 and contains $x_1+\delta_1$. Do this inductively until you have an interval that contains $y$. Verify this works.

Comment: And a perhaps better way of adjusting this proof that  avoids arranging terms so neatly: Select any interval $U_1$
  from the subcover, so $f$ is nondecreasing on $U_1$.  Select any $U_2$ from the subcover
  that intersects $U_1$   so $f$ is nondecreasing on $U_1\cup U_2$. If this process stops
  without covering all of $[x,y]$ obtain a contradiction.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: I think you are overcomplicating things: given that the set $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is finite, I can rearrange its elements in increasing order as $\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ by defining $y_i = \min \{x_i, \dots, x_n\}$. Therefore, my above reasoning is perfectly valid modulo such a permutation.

Comment: Think of your response here as an algorithm.  Mine is a "greedy algorithm" and yours is a "first-come, first served" algorithm.  You want your first interval to include the left-hand  endpoint $x$.  But for the smallest of the $x_i$ the corresponding interval may not include that point $x$.  It could even be the largest of the $x_i$ that does the job.  So your algorithm needs to be adjusted to work, valid with some amendments but not yet "perfectly valid."

Comment: I think Mr. M. has simply lost interest, since he knows how to correct his argument.  To finish things off:  (a) use Heine-Borel to get a finite subcover (b) remove from the subcover any redundant sets, i.e., sets that are contained in some other set (c)  relabel the centers so they are in order, $x_1<x_2<\dots < x_n$.  (d) prove that $x\in (x_1-\delta_1,x_1+\delta_1)$ using the fact that, if not then this interval would be contained in some other (e) claim that, *similarly*, $x_1+\delta_1$ (if less than $y$) is in the interval $(x_2-\delta_2,x_2+\delta_2)$. Etc.  Overcomplicated?

Comment: Last thoughts:  my answer (which no-one seems to like) points out that many students find the Cousin argument *on the real line* preferable to the Heine-Borel argument.  As you can see here, an HB argument can end up pretty fussy sometimes.  Even so, the HB argument is *far more important* since it generalizes nicely to far more situations.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch**: You can attempt a direct argument by considering the sets
\begin{align*}
X^{+} &= \{x > 0 : \text{$f$ is non-decreasing on $[0, x]$}\}, \\
X^{-} &= \{x < 0 : \text{$f$ is non-decreasing on $[x, 0]$}\}.
\end{align*}
Your statement A implies $X^{+}$ is non-empty and open. If $\ell = \sup X^{+}$ existed (i.e., were finite), statement A (with $x = \ell$) would get you into a contradiction; consequently, $\sup X^{+} = +\infty$, and $f$ is non-decreasing on $[0, \infty)$. A similar argument shows $\inf X^{-} = -\infty$.

(This strategy looks more straightforward than the contrapositive, though consideration of similar sets will help if you decide to proceed with the contrapositive.)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the pedagogue in me (or is it pedant?).  There is a general lesson here.  If you have a local condition (here *locally nondecreasing*) and you want to derive a global condition (*nondecreasing on* $\mathbb{R}$) the compactness arguments should immediately come to mind. (Indeed one of the answers specifically invokes the Heine-Borel theorem which is synonymous with compactness.)

On the real line there is a very convenient tool for constructing compactness arguments.  One of my colleagues was a bit worried for his students since they were so addicted to using it that he felt maybe it was a bit unwise, since it doesn't generalize to metric spaces even (as the Heine-Borel theorem does).  The students used the argument exclusively and would avoid any other compactness argument as too tedious.

Here is the argument:  let $\cal C$ be the collection of all intervals $[u,v]$ on which $f$ is nondecreasing.  That's a huge collection because of the assumption that $f$ is locally nondecreasing.  So huge in fact that for any interval $[a,b]$ you can split into pieces 
$$[a,a_1], [a_1,a_2], [a_2,a_3], \dots , [a_n,b]$$
where each of the pieces is in $\cal C$.  So, of course, $f$ is nondecreasing  on $[a,b]$ since it is nondecreasing on each of the pieces.

If you have never seen the argument before (it is in my textbook, but not in all elementary real analysis textbooks) here is what you need.

> **Definition.** A collection  $\cal C$ of closed intervals $[u,v]$ is said to be  *full* at a point $x$ if there is a $\delta>0$ [$\delta$ depends on $x$] so that
>   $[u,v]\in {\cal C}$ whenever $x\in [u,v]$ and $v-u<\delta$.
>
> **Cousin Covering Lemma**:  If $\cal C$ is full at every point of an
>   interval $[a,b]$ then $\cal C$ contains a partition of $[a,b]$.

With this tool available the solution to the posed problem is fast and simple: *Let  $\cal C$ be the collection of all intervals on which $f$ is nondecreasing.  This is full at each point by the assumption that $f$ is locally nondecreasing.  Since   $\cal C$ contains a partition of any interval $[a,b]$ [by Cousin's lemma], $f$ is nondecreasing on every interval.*